# Family hierarchy for forking processes

Tags: process, fork

I'm currently studying about how to fork (duplicate) a process. The result of the fork is having a Parent process and a Child process. My question is :

```
Let's suppose we have the process P-1.
We forked P-1, and we obtained a child process P-1.1.
I know that is possible to fork P-1 again and obtain P-1.2.
But my question is : 
Is is possible to fork the process P-1.1 and obtain a GrandChild for P-1 that we can call P-1.1.1?
```

I'm waiting for an aswer by "Possible" or "Not possible", but giving some **reasons** in **process management side** of making it "Not possible" (if  not possible :) ).

Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you wouldn't be able to fork a forked process, but it's not really an area I am an expert on...

Answer (score 0):

Possible.

P-1.1 is just another process, the fact that it's a child makes no difference.

Just call fork from P-1.1 and a new child process (P-1.1.1) will be created.